# Unauthorized error although token is loaded correctly

Tags: angular, auth0, angular2-jwt

I updated my Angular 6 app so that it uses the [auth0/angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) library. After I updated my services now, I get an `401 Unauthorized` error back from my API although a token is attached correctly to the header.

> Any requests sent using Angular's HttpClient will automatically have a token attached as an Authorization header.

This is the documentation for that: [Usage Injection](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#usage-injection)

So as far as I understood correctly, I don't need to load my token anytime I want to make an request, and than attach it to the headers because it gets loaded automatically. This is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: () => {
          return localStorage.getItem('id_token');
        },
        throwNoTokenError: true,
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:3000'],
      }
    }),
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  getProfile() {
    return this.http.get<profile>('http://localhost:3000/users/profile');
  }
```

If I use Postman with the token from my localStorage, everything works fine and I get back the correct profile data. If I use my Angular-App it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

return this.http
  .get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.localStorage.getItem('id_token')}`)
  });
```

Comment: That is working fine, but it's not like the documentation said, that a header is sent in every request automatically :/